# Get Max data against a ts and total count of record in single join query - POSTGRES

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, subquery

I have 2 tables with a foreign key. I have to get the counts of all the records in right table and the threshold value of max ts in right table.

TABLE alarm

| column | Datatype |
| --- | --- |
| id | PK |
| name | varchar |

TABLE alarm_data

| column | Datatype |
| --- | --- |
| alarm_id | FK |
| ts | timestamp |
| value | int |

I have to get total count of alarm_data associated with an alarm_id and the value of alarm_data with latest ts.

The expected output is

| alarm_id | ts | occurance_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123456 | 2 |

Queries I have used is
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/7351

It is always returning multiple records as I have to add alarm_data.value in group by. It should only return 1 record with value and occurence count.

Comment: It seems your sample data is incorrect. Your expected result contains a ts value of 123456, but the data in your fiddle doesn't have such a value. It's also unclear why/how to get an occurance_count of 2. This is likely also a mistake in your sample data. Please fix this.

Comment: Please put what is needed to ask in your post, not just at a link.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `row_number` function to get *the value of alarm_data with the latest ts*, and the count window function to get *the total count of alarm_data associated with an alarm_id*.

```
select A.id, 
       A.name,
       D.ts,
       D.cn as occurance_count,
       D.value
from alarm A join 
(
  select *, count(*) over (partition by alarm_id) cn,
     row_number() over (partition by alarm_id order by ts desc) rn
 from alarm_data
) D
on A.id = D.alarm_id
where D.rn = 1
```

[See demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/7353)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `group by` to get `count()` and `max(ts)`:

```
  select a.id as alarm_id, max(ad.ts) as ts, count(1) as occurance_count
  from alarm a
  inner join alarm_data as ad on a.id = ad.alarm_id
  group by a.id
```